# Why doesn't Nossor Ri appear in the Mon Cala arcs?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, Nossor Ri is the Quarren chieftain on Mon Cala, who allies himself with the Galactic Republic and the Mon Calamari king Lee-Char. Lee-Char later appears in the canon *Star Wars* and *Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith* comic book series, as well as other influential Mon Calamari such as Raddus and Ackbar. However, Nossor Ri is nowhere to be found. Why is this? He was quite an important member of the Mon Cala government, and his friendship with the Mon Calamari was necessary for both their peoples. Is there a canon reason for this?

Comment: To put it simply, Disney does not know what to do with Mon Cala and Mon Calamari, not to mention Quarren. On one hand, they put Mon Cala under Imperial occupation, like in comic you mentioned. On the other hand, they still want to supply Rebel fleet with Mon Calamari ships. I'm afraid that fate of Quarren is just afterthought in all of this.

Comment: @rs.29 Wasn't the Mon Cala under imperial occupation in EU as well? The ships they provided were converted passenger liners.  Also a potential answer is that they didn't know about the character. Keep in mind the Clone Wars was pre-disney acquisition, and even though it was the same story team, the direction was changed after the purchase.

Comment: @CBredlow Mon Cala was a mess in EU, but at least they had a story of them pushing Imperials from planet and sector, therefore giving at least some explanation for manufacture of large ships. Problem of large ships for Rebel Alliance was never successfully (logically) solved.